# Calculating Variance in Fortran using a Multi Dimensional Array - Not getting correct values

Tags: fortran, fortran90

```
PROGRAM  Assignment_8 

IMPLICIT NONE

REAL,DIMENSION(1440,11) :: data
INTEGER :: inputstatus, openstatus, i, j 
REAL :: TempSum = 0.0, MaxVal, MinVal, MaxPrecip = 0.0, MinPrecip = 10000.00, &
TempSumsq = 0.0, TempVar, Tempsd, WindSum = 0.0, WindSumsq = 0.0, Windsd, WindVar, &
WindAvg, dailyprecip, MaxTemp, MinTemp, AvgWind, AvgTemp
REAL(8) :: Pressure, PressureSum = 0.0, PressureSumsq = 0.0, PressureAvg, Pressuresd, &
PressureVar 
INTEGER :: Count = 0
CHARACTER(20) :: filename


! Prompts the user to open the file
WRITE (*, '(1X, A)', ADVANCE = "NO") "Enter the name of the file:"
READ *, filename
! This statement will specify the unit number, and how the file will be
! opened
OPEN (UNIT = 35, FILE = filename, STATUS = "OLD", ACTION = "READ", IOSTAT = openstatus)
IF (openstatus > 0) STOP "FILE CAN'T BE OPEN" 

! Reads the opened file, places in an array, and calculates the output
DO i = 1,1440
    READ(35, *, iostat = inputstatus) data(i,:)
    if   (inputstatus > 0) STOP "Could not fill array"
ENDDO

! Calculates the output
AvgTemp = sum(data(:,6))/size(data(:,6))
AvgWind = sum(data(:,8))/size(data(:,8))
PressureAvg = sum(data(:,10))/size(data(:,10))
TempVar = (sum(data(:,6))-(sum(data(:,6))/size(data(:,6))))**2
Tempsd = (TempVar)**(.5)
WindVar = (sum(data(:,8))-(sum(data(:,8))/size(data(:,8))))**2
Windsd = (WindVar)**(.5)
PressureVar = (sum(data(:,10))-(sum(data(:,10))/size(data(:,10))))**2
Pressuresd = (PressureVar)**(.5)
MaxTemp = maxval(data(:,6))
MinTemp = minval(data(:,6))
dailyprecip = maxval(data(:,6)) - minval(data(:,6))

! Converts Pressure (Hg) to Pressure (mb)
PressureAvg = PressureAvg * 33.8639
Pressuresd = Pressuresd * 33.8639

! Displays formatted output of calculations from the data
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A20)', "Average Temperature=", AvgTemp, "Degrees Fahrenheit"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A20)', "Temperature Variability=", Tempsd, "Degrees Fahrenheit"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A20)', "Maximum Daily Temperature=", MaxTemp, "Degrees Fahrenheit"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A20)', "Minimum Daily Temperature=", MinTemp, "Degrees Fahrenheit"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A5)', "Average Wind Speed=", AvgWind, "mph"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A5)', "Wind Speed Variability=", Windsd, "mph"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A10)', "Average Pressure=", PressureAvg, "Millibars"
PRINT '(1X,A30,F7.2,A10)', "Pressure Variability=", Pressuresd, "Millibars"
PRINT '(1X,A40,F7.2,A10)', "Daily Accumulated Precipitation=", dailyprecip, "Inches"

CLOSE (35)

END PROGRAM assignment_8
```

I am not getting the correct values for Standard Deviation. Are my variance equations correct?

I should be getting reasonable variability for Wind Speed, Pressure, and Temperature. Wind Speed variability should be .80, Pressure at .85, and temperature at 1.10

Comment: Welcome to SO! I formatted the question for you... However, there are still important pieces missing: What output did you get? What did you expect? What did you try to solve it? Did you enable all compiler warnings and checks? Also, please provide something that is compilable. Please read [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As we can't see the input data file, also note that `inputstatus>0` is not sufficient to detect whether the read was successful: negative values come about on end of file/record conditions.

Comment: The variance equations are wrong: if nothing else, you're squaring outside the summation.

Answer (score 2):

Standard deviation is:

[image]

but you are calculating:

[image]

You are missing a factor of 1/N under the square root and you should square the difference individual terms of the summation, not the sum itself.